# What does it mean when a file isn't detected with a wildcard search?

Tags: command-line, filesystems, filenames, wildcards

I have three files in a folder: `trace-0.fits`, `trace-1.fits`, `trace-2.fits`.

When I run:

```
ls trace-?.fits
```

Only `trace-0.fits` and `trace-2.fits` are detected. But:

```
ls trace-1.fits
```

Detects `trace-1.fits`, as expected.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Edit:
The OS is gentoo linux, and the file system is ext4. `ls *`, `ls`, `ls trace-*.fits`, and `ls *1*.fits` also do not show trace-1.fit. The system variable $GLOBIGNORE is not set, and `type ls` shows that ls is only aliased with the color option `` ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto ``

Comment: try `ls -b` to see if any special characters is there

Comment: Does `trace-1.fits` show up in the output of `ls` alone?

Comment: @phuclv If it had special characters in it, then the `ls` command that they say works would not work.

Comment: ```ls -b trace-1.fits``` just returns trace-1.fits. It is not in the output of ```ls``` alone.

Comment: What OS and filesystem is that? How about `ls *1*`?

Comment: Try again with the wildcard of * and not ? (? Matches the preceding element zero or one time)

Comment: @dhm that's regex. Here, `?` is a single character

Comment: Does `type ls` give anything other than `ls is /usr/bin/ls`?

Comment: Could you have excluded it unintentionally (for example, something like `GLOBIGNORE='*1*'` in bash)?

Comment: The OS is gentoo linux. ```ls *1*``` still misses trace-1.fits. 

```ls trace-*.fits``` also misses the file.

```type ls``` gives ```ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'``` I doubt that's the issue, but I could un-alias if we think that would be a useful experiment.

@steeldriver, how could I tell? ```echo $GLOBALIGNORE``` returns nothing, but could there be something else?

Comment: "`echo $GLOBALIGNORE` returns nothing" – The name of the relevant variable is `GLOBIGNORE`, not `GLOBALIGNORE`. You should also [quote right](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).

Comment: Thanks! ```echo $GLOBIGNORE``` also returns nothing. One question I missed from before, the file system is ext4.

Comment: things to try: 1. create (touch) those filenames in a different folder. 2. create some other files like abc-0.def abc-1.def etc. 3. what about trace-10.fits for example. 4. what if you rename that file, then rename it back. I'm just spitballing here, so much of that probably seems stupid, but lets face it, this problem looks impossible

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure what to make of this, but trace-1.fits completely disappeared. ```ls trace-1.fits```, which had previously detected it, no longer does. I ran ```touch trace-1.fits``` to re-create it, and it's now detected by ```ls trace-?.fits```. So, there's not much left to test here. However, I first stumbled across this quirk when looking into a software bug, which I'm nearly sure is related to this issue. I'm going to run the software again to see if I can trigger the problem again, although the the bug may center around a different filename.

Comment: Just an update: It turns out that this file system was badly corrupted. It's hard to replicate this specific error, but it seems very likely that this was due to the corruption.